# Search for substrings in given order

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write a function to search for given substrings in one or more strings in the order the substrings are given.  For example, if the substrings are

> "the" "new" "store"

and strings are

> "the new store is in san francisco", "the boy enters a new and cool
>   store", "a new boy enters the store", "there is newton in the store"

then the function will match only the 1st, 2nd, and 4th sentences because they have the substrings are the specific order, whereas the 3rd has them in the wrong order.

Comment: OK, so where is your code?

Comment: I don't have code yet, I want to know how to approach this, I mean can i search in string for tokens in specific order?

Comment: Any comments?, if you don't understand the problem i can try to explain it in a better way.

Comment: How *"there is newton in the store"* is ordered based on your tokens?

Comment: And also where did the sentence `"there is newton in the store"`  came from?

Comment: Their is "the" in "there", "new" in "newton" , that's how it matches, and these are just random sentences.

Comment: You confused people by calling substrings 'tokens'.  I edited question to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). `.+` matches 1 or more characters excluding `\n`. `.*` matches 0 or more characters.

```
import re

l = ["the new store is in san francisco", "the boy enters a new and cool store", "a new boy enters the store",
     "there is newton in the store"]

for i in l:
    m = re.search(r'the.+new.+store.*', i)
    if m:
        print(m.group())
```

Comment: Hello, I liked your answer very much But consider the string "the newstore is a brand", It contains all the three words in order, so it should be success, but according to your code, it's a failure.

Comment: @k3rn3l Glad to be of service. For any further explanation let me know.

Comment: Hello again, can you explain the regex you wrote. Also it doesn't match the example i gave in above comment.

Answer (score 1):

The key idea is to use string.index(sub, start) for each substring, with start initially 0 and incremented past each substring found.  If this is homework, and perhaps even if not, you should try writing subs_in_strings(subs, strings) yourself, before reading my answer.

..

```
def subs_in_strs(subs, strings):
    '''Yield strings that contain subs in order, without overlap.

    strings: iterable of strings
    subs: reiterable sequence of substrings
    '''
    for string in strings:
        dex = 0
        try:
            for sub in subs:
                dex = string.index(sub, dex) + len(sub)
            yield string
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Your test

```
for s in subs_in_strs(('the', 'new', 'store'),
        ("the new store is in san francisco",
         "the boy enters a new and cool store",
         "a new boy enters the store",
         "there is newton in the store",)):
    print(s)
```

The 3rd sentence is not printed.  Testing overlap condition:

```
for s in subs_in_strs(('sent', 'tense'),
        ('sent a tense note',
         'mispelled sentense',
         'another senttense')):
    print(s)
```

2nd is omitted, 3rd not, as per specification.